# how to get updated value in firebase angularjs

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

hi all i am using angularjs and firebase i have child node in db and i inserting the value from controller but not  able getting the updated scope value from firebase db i need to get updated value each time to store once scope array help how to solve that pblm.here i paste my tried code

## code

```
 var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('messages12');    
 $scope.messages = $firebaseArray(ref);
 firebase.database().ref().child('messages12').on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
        var data= snapshot.val();
$scope.gettingUpdatedvalue=[]//here i need updated  values 

    });
```

Comment: child_changed event will give you updated value each time when child node modified.